# Why python argparse module does not parse hash mark?

Tags: python, argparse

I need to get a list of hashtags from `sys.argv`. I use `argparse` module for this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-hashtag', nargs='*')
```

but when I launch script like this:

```
python filename.py -hashtags #one #two #three
```

I get 
    `Namespace(hashtag=[])`.

If I replace `#` sign by `*`, I normally get `Namespace(hashtag=['*one', '*two', '*three'])`. How make it work with hash sign?

Comment: In many (most?) shells, `#` denotes the start of a comment.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Ok, I got it. I think would be better enter them without hash mark.

Comment: With problems like this it is a good idea to print `sys.argv`, to see what the parser has to work with.

Comment: @0x1337 Are you sure that `*one` works?  Most shells will expand `*` as a glob if you don't quote it.

Comment: @SethMMorton In my shell `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)` it works.

Comment: @0x1337 I'll be honest, that would be a concern to me. You are sure you aren't quoting it?  Do globs work in your shell?

Comment: @SethMMorton I don't know what is globs, but it works without quots.

Comment: If on the shell you type `ls *.txt`, the `*.txt` is a glob. The shell looks for all files that end in .txt and then send them to the "ls" command. This is a fundamental part of any shell, and if the shell does not do this expansion there is likely something wrong.

Comment: @SethMMorton `ls *.any_extenshion_here` works properly. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In shell scripts, a `#` sign usually starts a comment. Prefix them with `\`.

```
python filename.py -hashtags \#one \#two \#three
```

Comment: Just to be crystal clear, the issue is not that Python isn't properly reading the `#` characters, but rather that the shell is not passing them to the Python process because they have special meaning to the shell. The same is true of the `*` character, or something like a variable (`$USER` would not be passed as is to Python, but would be expanded by the shell first). It's important to keep these things in mind when designing command-line interfaces.

Comment: Also, instead of the \ character one could quote each argument (as in `"#one"`).